# Straight sided serration dimensioning

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

[image]I have invented something and I need to have some external broaches made but I'm being asked for some dimensions I simply do not understand.

I need 4 external broaches. They all have the same major diameter 7.6 mm. They all have an angle of 90° between each spline. I do not need any radius in the root between the splines and the peaks can be sharp too. I need spline counts of 18, 20 24, and 28.

I am told by the toolmaker they cannot programme their machines until I give them numbers relating to pin diameter and a distance between pins.

I've Googled till my fingers bleed but nowhere can I find a definitive answer to the dimensions I need, how to work it out or even to describe what these things are and their relevance.

Hope the attached helps[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLKiN.jpg)

Comment: The standard for this type of serration is BS2059. It talks about a PIN or cylinder touching adjacent flanks at their midpoint.